# How to pass a integer array to not in conditions in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following case in PostgreSQL:

```
    xfields smallint[];
    xfields={1,2,3}

   select fields from table where fieldno not in (xfields);
```

if i execute the above query it shows error as " operator does not exist: smallint <> smallint[] "

can anyone help me how to pass the values in array in  the above query or how to execute the above conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array in query by using ALL or ANY functions.

For above query you can use

```
select fields from table where fieldno <> ALL(xfields);
```

[Check here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html)

Comment: please don't give links to old versions, OP uses 9.1, your link is to 8.2

Comment: @Roman: Thanks for the tip. I was trying to answer as quick as possible. My +1 goes to you for fiddle demo.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation about it's here [Row and Array Comparisons v 9.1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html) or [latest version](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html).

```
select fields
from table
where fieldno <> all(xfields);
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f6b35/1)